# Changing char array

Tags: c++, matrix, char

I've been trying to develop a connsole mineseeker just to test my knowledge in a random project since I'm new to programming. In the console I show a matrix of 'O' to represent the possible mines. At the upper and right edges I wanted to print '0 1 2 3 4 5...' so it could be easier to understand how to input the matrix point that the user selects. 
I print a new line over the matrix to do the upper edge, but when I want to show the right edge, I can't change the last column to print what I want. I can change the column before the last one, but when I try to do it with the last one, the console is called but it doesn't print anything and stops working.

previously I create a matrix of objects "Mineseeker" where a char is what is shown in the console and a bool represents if a object is a bomb or not.

```
class MineSeeker{
bool bomb;
char show;
static int counter; //change static
public:
    MineSeeker();
    void setBomb();
    void setShow(char isShow);
    char showChar();
    void setLast(char last);
    static int rCounter();
 };    

void MineSeeker::setLast(char last){
 show = last;
}

for (int a; a < rows; a++){
    newlast = 'a'; //first trying to make it work with any char.
    mine[a][6].setLast(newlast); //6 is the last column. rows = 6, cols =7.
}
```

Does somebody now why can't I change the last column of the matrix?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You'd do well to look into a "try/catch" combination and `GetLastError()`, provided you're okay with using the Windows headers.

Comment: What type is `mine`?

Comment: `for (int a; a < rows; a++)`  What is the initial value of `a`?

Comment: 1. Check dimensions of mine matrix (should be 6 x 7 - then bottom right element would be mine[5][6]).
2. You probably don't set initial value of 'a' inside for loop, check it out.